# Cannot open files in Sharepoint search results

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search-results, office-web-apps

I am using SharePoint Server 2013 and I am trying to open files from the search results. When I search a specific file, the search returns my answer perfectly. However, when I try to open the file, I got a server error. I copied the link of the file and pasted it a new window, but I got the same error.
Any ideas, please? 
[image]

Comment: On Prem? (I assume yes) What kind of file. Can you view documents from Document Libraries? What have you done to troubleshoot? Are you running OWA?

Comment: @Matthew McDermott I am using SharePoint Server 2013 and I tried all files type such as Excel and word. I can open them directly through the library but when I search for a document then open it, I got the error. It seems that the problem in opening the documents in the browser!! Do you know how can I check if OWA is running? For now, I am using client application to open the documents from SP.

Comment: Check answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by troubleshooting OWA. If OWA works in the Document library then I would perform a full crawl. This will reindex the document and set the link to OWA. I have see cases where Alternate Access Mapping is not correctly configured and the crawl is not being performed on the default zone.